# PHP: have GD able to print Japanese words

Tags: php, unicode, gd

In a PHP module, We have a few graphics made by GD that need to have some Japanese words in it.
These words are entered manually from a form by Japanese users, and that text should be displayed within the graphics.

PHP has the `mbstring` module and can display and handle Japanese words via echo with no problem.

However `gd` displays `???` instead.

Checking `gd_info()`, the following configuration is set

```
JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support: Disabled
```

This could be the problem. But I didn't find how to `Enable` it.

Using PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neet to re-compile php with --enable-gd-jis-conv

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=694939

Comment: Thanks, but is there any no-recompilation-needed solution?

Comment: Depends on your OS I guess, some might bundle a jis-compatible version.

Comment: Is it possible to compile only the gd module (including the JP option)?